# Multi-level inheritance: Calling a method only ONE level higher from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

Basically, I have 3 classes

```
class abstract A{}
   protected aMethod(){}

class abstract B extends A{
   protected aMethod(){}
}

class C extends B{
  // How do I call B.aMethod() from here? As super.aMethod() 
  // would call A.aMethod()?
}
```

See the code. I want to call a method one class higher that the lowest level. But calling super.aMethod() would return the root class implementation?

EDIT: Turns out super does just go one level higher, god knows what I was trying... Rookie mistake, apologies all!

Comment: Why do you think it would call `A.aMethod()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super.aMethod()` would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually calling super.aMethod() from C, should call aMethod() in B and not in A.

Answer (score 0):

```
super.aMethod()
```

should work fine if B implements the method.

Also, just as a note on your tag, multiple-inheritance speaks towards "extending" more than one base class, for example:

```
public C extends B, A { ... } // WRONG SYNTAX!
```

which is not supported by Java.